# Why does the filter() function not return my expected type-filtered array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter, typescript-typings

[image]

I think I have a misconception with Typescript.
As I understand, after the filter function there will be no undefined in the array. So the return value of filter function will be initialization value of box variable

I can fix it in this way, but I would rather use the same logic as short way as possible:
[image]

How can I fix the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's annoying, but you have to explicitly set the type predicate in the inner function. Something like this:

```
const box: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, undefined].filter((d): d is number => d !== undefined)
```

The `d is number` part tells the compiler that indeed this function ensures that this item is a number. You can also make yourself an utility function

```
export function isPresent<T>(t: T | undefined | null | void): t is T {
  return t !== undefined && t !== null;
}

const box: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, undefined].filter(isPresent)
```

Comment: But I'm not sure why.
I need to declare "d is number", but it is not true. d is "number | undefined". 
Do you have a link for explanation of "d is number" functionality? I've never used "x IS something" before.

Comment: It's called type predicates https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

In it you specify what type are you sure the item will be after the function. So in your case `d is number`  would be correct after executing the filter.  You basically tell the compiler "I'm sure that this variable here is number after calling this function". 

It's a very requested feature to automatically do that for filters, you can upvote it here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to fix the message with type casting:

```
const box: number[] = <number[]>[
  1, 2, 3, 4, undefined
].filter( d => typeof d !== 'undefined')
```